# Should DNS (PTR Records) be configured differently for different ipv6 networks?

Tags: rhel, ipv6, bind

I am configuring DNS forward and reverse lookup for IPv6(Redhat).
For both  /64 and /120  prefix i am using below configuration for PTR records.

for address 6b00:8a00:a000:11a1::a2b:1c9f

(Only a part of configuration)

$ORIGIN 1.a.1.1.0.0.0.a.0.0.a.8.0.0.b.6.ip6.arpa.
...
..
..

f.9.c.1.b.2.a.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0 PTR  hostname

I tried for below configuration also ,but it didn't work

$ORIGIN b.2.a.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.a.1.1.0.0.0.a.0.0.a.8.0.0.b.6.ip6.arpa.

f.9.c.1 PTR hostname

So, can i go with the first configuration without bothering about network prefix and mask.

Comment: Please show the real data. The IPv6 addresses you use are bogons

Comment: due to security reason can't show real data ,but you can ask about format.     $ORIGIN b.2.a.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.a.1.1.0.0.0.a.0.0.a.8.0.0.b.6.ip6.arpa.

f.9.c.1 PTR hostname                                                                                                is configuration of reverse lookup file

Comment: As long as you have 32 hexadecimal characters separated with dots before ip6.arpa, and delegation from your upstream/registry properly configured it should work. How you split ORIGIN and the records doesn't matter. The most common mistakes are typos and bad delegation, but because you refuse to show the real data I can't help you with that.

Comment: By real  data you mean ipv6 address of node  ,which is below:-  2a00:8a00:a000:11a1::a2b:1b91.